Sklearn EstimatorCV vs GridSearchCV
sklearn has the following description for EstimatorCV estimators:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-cross-validation-estimator

An estimator that has built-in cross-validation capabilities to automatically select the best hyper-parameters (see the User Guide). Some example of cross-validation estimators are ElasticNetCV and LogisticRegressionCV. Cross-validation estimators are named EstimatorCV and tend to be roughly equivalent to GridSearchCV(Estimator(), ...).

As far as I understand, cross-validation is used for testing generalizability. GridSearch is used for identifying optimal hyperparameters. Ideally, for each grid search hyperparameter combination, we would perform a cross-validated assessment of the estimator using those hyperparameters.
How is the EstimatorCV able to automatically select the best hyper-parameters?
How is it equivalent to GridSearchCV(Estimator)?
Why isn't it equivalent to cross_validate(Estimator)?
Am I missing something fundamental, or is this explanation incorrect?

The rest of the documentation basically gives the answer:

The advantage of using a cross-validation estimator over the canonical
estimator class along with grid search is that they can take advantage
of warm-starting by reusing precomputed results in the previous steps
of the cross-validation process. This generally leads to speed
improvements.

Note that most (if not all) EstimatorCVs only have a single (main) hyper-parameter like the regularization parameter in LogisticRegressionCV.
cross_validate is used to estimate model metrics not for hyper-parameters.

I was assuming that an EstimatorCV was a combination of the estimator and cross validation and didn't include grid searching.
This quote confused me:
"An estimator that has built-in cross-validation capabilities to automatically select the best hyper-parameters".
I didn't understand how cross validation would automatically select the best hyperparameters and replace the need for grid searching. It seems that the estimatorCV does grid search. If it was called estimatorGSCV I wouldn't be confused
